# First term of math formula

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm currently at comprehending the logic of the first term in the formula.

Why is 45 included in the multiplication. And also why is 'i' being multiplied.
The formula calculates the sum of all digits of all numbers upto from 1 to N. For example if N = 11, sum will be 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) = 48.

```cpp
long long sum(long long N){
    if(N/10==0) return N*(N+1)/2;
    int i=0;
    long long n=N;
    while(n/10!=0){
        i++;
        n/=10;
    }
    int p=pow(10,i);
    return ((n*45*i*p/10)+ n*(n-1)*p/2+ n*(N%p+1) + sum(N%p));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that works.  If I put input 11 into your function, I think I get 45 + 0 + 2 + 1, where I expect 2.  I would expect something like this rough effort:

```
unsigned long long sum_digits(unsigned long long N) {
  size_t exp = std::log10(N);

  unsigned long long result = 0u;
  for (size_t i = 0u; i <= exp; ++i) {
    //isolate the (i+1)th digit
    long long ub = std::pow(10, i+1);
    long long lb = std::pow(10, i);
    size_t digit = (N % ub) / lb;

    //add the digit's contribution to the sum
    result += digit * (digit + 1) / 2;
  }

  return result;
}
```

I'd expect a sum of digits to look more like that, but I may just misunderstand the aim of this algorithm.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood the question. The function calculates the sum of all digits of all numbers from 1 to N.